# Sort Filter Comare array of objects in a particular format

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, javascript-objects

Sort my json in format as below :

```
    [{"x":"Jan-2017","y":41},{"x":"Feb-2017","y":20},{"x":"Mar-2017","y":45},{"x":"Apr-2017","y":29},{"x":"May-2017","y":59},{"x":"Jun-2017","y":378},{"x":"Jul-2017","y":354},{"x":"Aug-2017","y":398},{"x":"Sep-2017","y":390},{"x":"Oct-2017","y":579},{"x":"Nov-2017","y":651},{"x":"Dec-2017","y":832}]
```

for example :

If I have json as below :

```
    [{"x":"Aug-2017","y":398},{"x":"Oct-2017","y":579},{"x":"Nov-2017","y":651},{"x":"Dec-2017","y":832}]
```

result should be :

```
    [{"x":"Jan-2017","y":0},{"x":"Feb-2017","y":0},{"x":"Mar-2017","y":0},{"x":"Apr-2017","y":0},{"x":"May-2017","y":0},{"x":"Jun-2017","y":0},{"x":"Jul-2017","y":0},{"x":"Aug-2017","y":398},{"x":"Sep-2017","y":0},{"x":"Oct-2017","y":579},{"x":"Nov-2017","y":651},{"x":"Dec-2017","y":832}]
```

Any help or hint please will really help me out.

Comment: did u try smth?

Comment: That's an array of objects and not [JSON](http://json.org). _"JSON is a textual, language-indepedent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML."_ - [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich I was trying to do by makiing an angular filter with some standard data :

Comment: is the data sorted?

Comment: no the data is not sorted

Comment: Look at `array.prototype.sort` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an array for the months, sort the given data by year and month and use an index for the data array for maping a whole year until all years are mapped.

```js
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    data = [{ x: "Aug-2017", y: 398 }, { x: "Oct-2017", y: 579 }, { x: "Nov-2017", y: 651 }, { x: "Dec-2017", y: 832 }]
        .sort(({ x: a }, { x: b }) => {
            var aa = a.split('-'),
                bb = b.split('-');
            return aa[1] - bb[1] || months.indexOf(aa[0]) - months.indexOf(bb[0]);
        }),
    index = 0,
    year = data[0].x.slice(-4),
    result = [];

do {
    result.push(...months.map(month =>
        data[index] && data[index].x.slice(0, 3) === month
            ? data[index++]
            : { x: [month, year].join('-'), y: 0 }
    ));
} while (year++ < data[data.length - 1].x.slice(-4))

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what are you working so hard for? That's just too much complication for a relatively simple task.

Comment: thanx @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortElements(arr){
arr.sort((a, b) => 
  new Date(a.x).getTime() - new Date(b.x).getTime()
);
}
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should also contain an explanation on how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of moment.js to get all months and than traverse through it and create output array from it.

```js
 var input = [{"x":"Aug-2017","y":398},{"x":"Oct-2017","y":579},{"x":"Nov-2017","y":651},{"x":"Dec-2017","y":832}]
var allmonths = moment.monthsShort();
var year = 2017;
var output = allmonths.map((el,i) => {
let temp;
 return input.some((a) =>  a.x == el+"-"+year ? temp = a:false) ? temp:{x:el+"-"+year,y:0};
});
 
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```